# Arduino web server-how to get values form URL

Tags: ethernet

I’ve already searched through the internet but cannot find satisfactory answer.
Is there an easy way to get value of variable passed through an URL?
What I mean is I want to start a web server on my Arduino then call the URL like `10.0.0.1/?var1=x&var2=y` from my browser and read `var1` and `var2` to my program.
I could also use JSON format but how to send it to my Arduino and then read it?
I use Arduino Ethernet Shield W5100.
Any ideas?

Comment: you could use a WebServer library which among other things parses the parameters